# Secure Consul with SSL does not work

Tags: ssl, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, consul

I’m trying to secure consul with SSL. I have created my own certificate authority (CA) that is cacert.pem, and created a certificate for localhost that is localhost.pem. The current working directory looks as below.

```
certs/cacert.pem
certs/localhost.pem
config/config.json
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM consul:0.7.5
ADD ./config /consul/config/
ADD ./certs /certs/
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/consul", "agent", "-server",  "-bootstrap-expect=1", "-ui", "-data-dir=/consul/data", "-client=0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:

   myconsul:
    image: myconsul:0.7.5
    volumes:
      - /consul/data
      - /consul/config
    ports:
      - "8300:8300"
      - "8400:8400"
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8600:8600"
      - "8080:8080"
    command: agent -server -bootstrap-expect=1 -ui -client=0.0.0.0
```

config.son:

```
{
  "data_dir": "/consul/data",
  "config_dir": "/consul/config", 
  "log_level": "INFO",
  "server": true,
  "addresses": {
    "https": "0.0.0.0"
  },
  "ports": {
    "https": 8080
  },
  "cert_file": "/certs/localhost.pem",
  "ca_file": "/certs/cacert.pem"
}
```

I build the consul image by: docker build -t myconsul:0.7.5 . 
And run the consul container by: docker-compose up -d

http://192.168.99.100:8500/ works, but if I replace the ip address with localhost it does not work
 https://192.168.99.100:8080/ does not work

Questions:

1. why does the http link starts with locahlost not work?
2. I logged into the running container and found config.son in the expected location, but how can I make sure that consul was actually reading the
   configuration file?
3. what is the correct way to make SSL works in Consul?

Anyone can help? Is there any place I can post such questions?

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it, just:

1.- Delete "config_dir": "/consul/config", from config.json

2.- Add a key_file to the config.json

3.- Add -config-dir=/consul/config in docker-compose.yml (At the end of the command)